# Making [iphone], [ipod-touch] and [ipad] tags synonyms of the inclusive [ios]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

What do you think about making the [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone), [ipod-touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipod-touch) and [ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipad) tags synonyms of [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios)? I feel these are no longer necessary, and I see people removing them from questions all the time lately.

My reasons for making these tags synonyms:

1. Most **questions are very general**, and have nothing to do specifically with either iPhone or iPad devices. These questions would benefit either devices, but may be overlooked by newbies unfamiliar with iOS, thus making them ask a duplicate question.
2. Most **applications are universal**, and thus need to include general iOS logic, not iPad or iPhone specific logic; removing these tags will encourage correct and universal coding.
3. **Apple is moving away from idiom-specific API** - this is the most important one. Apple wants universal apps that look good, no matter the device idiom or size or scale. Going forward, the API will be independent of idioms and sizes, but dependent on what they call size classes. This API is common to pads and phones. Moreover, classes that used to be iPad exclusive, such as `UISplitViewController` and `UIPopoverController`, are now available universally and change their behavior depending on the size class of the presenting/presented view controller.

I think we should encourage people to write correct code, according to Apple guidelines. Removing these tags will do so. Removing will also help eliminate some duplicate questions from people that ask similar questions for different device idioms.

What do you guys think?

**Edit:** Changed my question to use tag synonym instead of burninate. Sounds like a great idea by @SantaClaus.

---

To address a few concerns that have risen from some commenters and answers, web development does really negate the need to remove these tags. Web development is not device specific, it is browser-specific and ios-version specific. Some examples have been brought about questions that make a mention of iPad. Just because there is a mention does not make the question only relevant to iPad, it's just the state of mind that the original asked had.
Likewise, hardware questions, that have risen as arguments for keeping the tags, don't seem to really be about iPhone and iPad, but more of architecture nature.

When answering and/or commenting against my proposal, please provide example questions where iPhone and iPad separation is really key to the question. I have not found one yet.

Comment: Brillant idea. In fact most Apps right now are not universal, but they now share the same API except for few cases (and older iOS versions)

Comment: The only bad thing about it is that I didn't think of it earlier.

Comment: There are in fact legitimate uses for the hardware specific tags.  Especially the iPad 3, which has a lot of execution problems compared to the others.  So be sure to consider that in any decision that is being made.  Most questions do not use them correctly, but a few still do.  On the other hand, it's not likely that removing the tags or making them synonyms will make the question any more difficult to find since the gold badges probably watch the "objective-c" and "ios" tags anyway.

Comment: @borrrden Agreed, but these questions are not good fit for the `ipad` tay anyway, since the same execution problems would exist on iPhone 4 as well. This is what the subject is for, and the question body - describing the issue.

Comment: For historical reference, we've had this discussion before (in the other direction): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85188/break-the-ios-iphone-synonym, and it was generally agreed that we should keep the device-specific tags separate. For all of Apple's efforts to unify the platform, I still see many device-specific things that people could ask about. A bigger problem are all the people tagging with only SDK-version-specific tags and none of the others, since those quickly get lost.

Comment: "How do I take photos with the back camera on iOS without looking like a jerk?" "Use an iPhone."

Comment: @BoltClock Gladly, such difficult questions are not for StackOverflow... `:-D`

Comment: This looks like another case of subtags (or tag tags, or tag categories) rather than tag synonyms.  All of `iphone` and `ipad` and `ios` should belong to the `ios` tag-category.

Comment: What about [ipod-touch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipod-touch)?

Comment: I'm one of those people removing the [tag:iphone] tag from a lot of iOS posts. I disagree with getting rid of them or making them synonyms. While the tags are misused by a lot of users, they have valid uses. The comments below the answer by "conner" covers some proper uses of the tags.

Comment: Indeed, @rmaddy. The specific iPhone and iPad tags have their place, but they should not be so easy to misuse for general iOS questions. Maybe what we need is a *conditional* tag synonym. It would kick in by default, synonymizing [iphone], [ipad], etc. to [ios], but it would be *overridable* (perhaps with sufficient reputation, like creating new tags?) when you really are asking something specific to those devices.

Comment: As a web developer, I can imagine many cases where a responsive web page would have issues *only* with iPhone/iPod Touch or *only* on iPad.

Answer (score 38):

I disagree. All three of the tags have their purpose:

- [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) for general questions about developing on iOS
- [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone) for questions specific to an iPhone device
- [ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipad) for questions specific to an iPad device

There are some differences between the devices. I agree that the tag gets misused, but that's no reason to burninate/merge a useful tag. That same argument could be made for the xcode tag as well.

Some example questions that are device specific:

[What to name images for iPhone 5 screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519110/what-to-name-images-for-iphone-5-screen-size)

[Customized UIPopoverController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486565/customized-uipopovercontroller)

[Why my iAds ads corrupted on iPads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210568/why-my-iads-ads-corrupted-on-ipads)

---

While [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone), [ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipad) and [xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode) are some of the most commonly misused tags on the site, they still serve a purpose.

Perhaps what we need is a system that pushes users towards using tags correctly. For commonly misused tags (as decided by the community) it could have a pop up appear telling the user how the tag should be used and have them confirm they want to use the tag. The pop up could go away if the user has a certain amount of rep or tag score. This wouldn't be perfect, but could probably cut the misuse of tags down to a manageable level.

Comment: Please post in your answer legitimate questions that are dependent on iPhone alone or iPad alone. This is obviously now what Apple wants you to think of when developing for iOS.

Comment: @LeoNatan I agree with your request for examples of the usefulness of the device-specific tags but entirely disagree with your reasoning. Nobody on SO should care about "what Apple wants you to think" or "what Apple wants" in general - we should care about the usefulness of the tags regardless of any policies or "best practices" preached by outside entities.

Comment: @l4mpi Apple are creating the ecosystem, and they are in best possession to set best practices for iOS development. Apple is not an outside entity to iOS. But whatever you think on the issue of Apple, there are other reasons where these tags are redundant.

Comment: @LeoNatan they are an outside entity **for SO**. If they say you should only use `iOS` but the SO community says that device specific tags are needed, then we should listen to the SO community and not apple. I do in fact agree that the tags seem superfluous and should be synonymized unless there are good reasons against it, but wanted to comment on your flawed reasoning. "Company X says [...]" is just not a valid argument for anything on SO, ever.

Comment: @l4mpi Guidelines are guidelines, everyone should decide for themselves how much value they put in them. I happen to put some value in it, as I agree with this guideline. I do happen to use what some people think is private API, but I always put a warning that people should be careful - because Apple advices against it. Here the API is warranting a change in programming direction, and there is no reason to fight it, just to preserve SO's independence from Apple.

Comment: here's a quick example @LeoNatan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210568/why-my-iads-ads-corrupted-on-ipads

Comment: @connor That is exactly why these tags are bad - if he had use the **correct initializer method** (`initWithAdType:`), he would not have had to worry about pad or phone idioms. Oh and looky looky, another tags dump question.

Comment: I think the tags have as much value as any of the other ones that are closely tied to ios like UITableView or UIViewController. I think those tags, along with iphone and ipad tags are useful to people. I'm sure there are some developers who hate working with ipads and would want to ignore all ipad questions and another may have a lot of experience with UITableViews and have an interest in solving difficult problems with it.

Comment: Uhm, solving a problem with tables on the iPad is 99.9% sure to help iPhone developers as well. That's the point. Limiting yourself to question tagged as `iphone` only is not a good practice.

Comment: I'm not saying tableviews are different on each device. I'm saying it's another subset of ios questions. There are problems that occur on one device but not another like in that question. He may have done something wrong, like you said, but don't most questions involve someone doing something wrong?

Comment: @LeoNatan you're comparing apples with oranges. A guideline that says "this is a private api subject to change or removal" should be taken seriously when you consider using it. But a guideline that says "please refer to all iphone/ipad development as ios development" seems just like plain brand awareness crap on the same level as "please capitalize the p in iphone/ipad". It is simply not a rational argument against using device specific tags as it does not, on its own, say anything about the consequences of doing so. Please make your arguments stand on your own instead of saying "X said so".

Comment: @l4mpi If you say that, then you are clearly not familiar with iOS8 APIs and how much Apple has improved their API to not distract developers with device (or size) specifics. Also, where are the Android device-specific tags? Why not have 3.5" and 4.0" specific tags?

Comment: @LeoNatan did you read anything I said? I'm not talking about the different APIs or whatever they improved or made worse, I'm talking about the fact that a statement like "you don't need device specific tags" on its own, without any actual evidence **why**, is not a rational argument. Period. Like I said in my previous comment, Apple also say that "iphone" is wrong and it should be "iPhone" - would you recommend changing the tag capitalization because of this?

Comment: @l4mpi No, because they have no say on how to style tags. They do have a say on how to use their API, which is why I give weight to what tags are less than optimal. On the other hand, I would not say "remove the `iphoneos-private-api` tag" just because Apple recommends against. These tags specifically are related to API use, and I have stated my reasons **why** I think they should be removed. One of them is Apple engineering recommending against such logic when using the API Apple engineering has designed. Agree or disagree, that's your prerogative.

Comment: @l4mpi On the other hand, if this was a publishing site (like TheVerge, Ars, etc.) and we used "iphone" instead of "iPhone" as a label, then yes, I would say "rename because Apple tells us how to name the product" - because users are more familiar with this name **and** because Apple has deemed to name it so, with a capital 'P'.

Comment: @LeoNatan Re your original first point, web development for mobile devices: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849069/website-displaying-differently-on-desktop-browser-vs-ipad-browser, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023804/web-page-upload-file-not-working-on-ipad, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874770/ipad-website-fullscreen-in-safari, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402081/website-left-aligned-on-ipad

Comment: @thegrinner ? None of these are iPad specific. Just because the user tested on iPad, does not make them specific to pad idiom. Same issues would arise on any iOS device.

Comment: @LeoNatan The point is those *aren't iOS questions*. They could be iPad, iPhone, or iPod, but at no point are those iOS. They're really [tag:html], [tag:css], [tag:javascript], or whatever other web development language is relevant, and how that language interacts with a specific device.

Comment: @LeoNatan Here is an example.  When the iPhone 5S came out, it broke face detection in the Core Image API.  This issue was specific to the iPhone 5S because of its new 64-bit architecture.  So it is not a general iOS problem but a problem with a specific piece of hardware.

Comment: @borrrden So it was broken on iPad Air as well? Just proved my point. Someone with the same problem on Air may miss the question because it was tagged as iPhone.

Comment: @LeoNatan There was 1 1/2 months between the release of the iPhone 5S and the iPad Air.  We ran into this problem before the release of the iPad Air so at the time it was iPhone 5S only.  Of course, this is not a usual situation but it happens from time to time.  When I mentioned the iPad 3, I meant that I was using code that worked well on the iPad 2, but had very poor performance on the iPad 3.  These things happen occasionally.  Furthermore, there could be issues with libraries not executing on the device, but executing in the simulator.

Comment: I'm not opposed to merging the tags though, since almost always the question is additionally tagged with [tag:ios] anyway.

Comment: Whatever the correct tagging is, people will always tag incorrectly. Just because the [iphone] is supposed to be iPhone-specific, that doesn't mean people wouldn't abuse the hell out of it. If it's misused more than used correctly, it's a bad tag.

Comment: @bjb568 I wouldn't call the `xcode` tag bad, and that one is misused all the time.

Comment: @thegrinner So they are neither iphone or ipad question then as well, right? I do not see how this is a point against merging of the tags. Some future reader experiencing the same problem on the other device might very well not find them as is but if the tag he had to search and that had been used on those questions had been iOs, he would. So imho that is much more an argument for making them synonyms...

Comment: @LeoNatan Well, people care enough about [xcode] to clean it up. It's too important to burninate anyway.

Comment: @bjb568 I have never said to burninate [xcode]. I am saying that [iphone] and [ipad] are unnecessary.

Comment: @LeoNatan I know. I'm just differentiating them.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the disagreement. @thegrinner If a question is about HTML, CSS or JS "running on a specific device", it should be tagged with **[mobile-safari]**, **[webkit]**, or even **[uiwebview]**. There's no such thing as *device-specific* web development, though there might exist *engine-specific* one.

Comment: And **even if** someone is asking a device-specific question, [iphone] tag is semantically invalid. iPhone is a family, not a device (unless we're talking about the first-gen one, and I doubt we are). For those questions, tags like [iphone-**3gs**], [iphone-**4**], [iphone-**4s**], [iphone-**5**], [iphone-**5s**], (and so on) should be used instead.

Comment: @akashivskyy I'm going to have to strongly agree with your disagreement with the disagreement.

Comment: @akashivskyy, if the specific devices are valid tags then why isn't the family? If there is a question that involves an issue that occurs on all iPhones running ios7 what should the user tag the question with? iPhone4, iPhone4s, iPhone5, iPhone5c, and iPhone5s or iOS, iOS7 and iPhone?

Comment: @connor Then the issue is broad enough to be classified with [ios] tag.

Comment: And it should be, but it's only applicable to iPhones

Comment: If the problem occurs on iPhone, it occurs on iPad. Show me one problem that is "specific to an iPhone device"? None of the ones you posted fit that description, or are no longer the optimal solutions to only take into account the iPhone side (size)

Comment: @LeoNatan - Despite attempted unification of the various device classes, there are indeed things that are unique to specific devices. Even in iOS 8, the iPhone has HealthKit, where the iPad does not. I run into subtle GPU differences between the iPhone and iPad hardware all the time. The iPhone is a cell phone and has associated telephony features, where the iPad does not. That may or may not be enough to justify keeping them separate, but there are differences between the devices which affect how you go about developing for them.

Comment: @BradLarson There are probably some few questions that are truly dependent. But they are so far in between, I am not sure the tags are really necessary. So far, only you have been able to provide a convincing example. Anyway, the people have spoken. I give up.

Answer (score 23):

Make them [tag synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms). [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone) and [ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipad) would become tag synonyms of the master tag [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios).

From the privilege page:

> **What are tag synonyms?**
>
> Tag synonyms allow us to fix incorrect tags by substituting them with
>   the correct tags.
>
> **When should I propose a tag synonym?**
>
> Whenever you see questions being repeatedly tagged with the wrong or
>   incorrect tag -- or multiple tags that mean the same thing -- it's a
>   good idea to propose a tag synonym.

This would automagiclly change any uses of the tag into the correct tag:

> **What happens when a question is asked using a synonym?**
>
> Any tags that match active synonyms will be automatically and silently
>   changed from their original as-entered form to the tag that the
>   synonym points to.

I would encourage someone with 2,500+ rep to go ahead and suggest this tag synonym, and see what happens.

Burination requires manual removal of every question with the [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone) and [ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipad) tags, whereas tag synonyms are handled automagiclly to an extent.

Comment: Excellent idea, I changed my question to reflect this idea. Makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 6):

### Don't make them synonyms, rename them

We should not get rid of device-specific tags for the reasons stated by connor and thegrinner, but we shouldn't keep the iphone and ipad tags either, as this obviously encourages confusion.

These tags should probably be renamed to something like 'iphone-specific' or 'iphone-device', with a proper description.

Comment: iphone-hardware would be useless, as I doubt there are actually any mfi hardware developers asking questions on SO, and also, mfi is idiom-agnostic, so again should be apple-mobile-hardware. `;-)`

Comment: I should have said 'device' instead of 'hardware'. I edited to reflect that I wasn't thinking specifically of hardware, but of questions really linked to one kind of device and not the other. Again, it's just a hunch, we should really check the stats to decide.

Comment: Can you provide an example in that such a tag would benefit the question?

Comment: @LeoNatan: For what it's worth questions about MFi do show up occasionally. Not often, though — I'm pretty sure MFi devs are under a specific NDA…

Comment: connor and thegriner gave many examples, so I edited my answer to remove the need for further corroboration of my hunch.

Answer (score 5):

**No!**

While some people are obviously mistagging questions with only a hardware tag (or a hardware tag in place of the iOS tag), there are legitimate uses of hardware tags:

- Problem/constraint unique to a specific form factor (iPad vs iPhone/iPod, like [modal view presentation on iPad](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/viewcontrollerpgforiphoneos/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html))
- Problem unique to the hardware iPad/iPhone and **not** involving iOS (like [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849069/website-displaying-differently-on-desktop-browser-vs-ipad-browser) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023804/web-page-upload-file-not-working-on-ipad) [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874770/ipad-website-fullscreen-in-safari) [web development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402081/website-left-aligned-on-ipad))

For reference, [synonymizing was done before and then undone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85242/164454).

Comment: The last paragraph of the previous attempt stands here. `iOS` has become the predominate way to tag questions. We should reexamine. Modal presentation has change a lot since 2011. Web development should use a `safari-ios`, not device, just like you don't add tags of `dell-xps-13` to a question related to desktop web development.

Comment: If there are multiple possible (and valid) synonyms for the different usages of the iPad/iPhone tags, then we can't fix this with a single tag synonym. Consider a couple of those questions I linked in the second point: the first and second are only tagged iPad, which if changed to iOS would break what little association they had with the question entirely. Also, tagging it with the browser won't help - all you'll do is shift the problem from iOS/iPad/iPhone to <web language/mobile/etc>/Safari/Chrome, since Safari isn't the sole browser for iDevices.

Comment: @LeoNatan My basic point is there can be / is a difference between iOS development and iPhone development.

Comment: I understand that, but I am not sure web development should dictate these tags remain functional. Likewise, there aren't Android tags for all possible variants of phones and tablets.

Comment: There isn't a fundamental difference between the devices. Do you distinct between 1024x768 desktop and a 2560x1440 desktop? You should - that's the only difference between the two browsers on pad and phone.

Comment: @LeoNatan So maybe we need a different tag that iPad and iPhone could be synonyms of, like "iOS-device"?

Comment: `ios-device` and `ios` sound to me a lot similar. I'd understand `ios-web-development` and `apple-mobile-hardware` or `apple-mfi`. But `ios-device` doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @LeoNatan, different desktop resolutions and tablet vs phone are not analogous.

Answer (score 2):

if someone TYPES IN "iPhone" as a tag, would it automatically bring up "iOS" ?

(and indeed, not allow them to enter "iPhone")

If so - it should be done.

Secondly - would it affect broader google searches somehow?

people REALLY like typing and searching on "iPhone" when they actually mean "apple stuff".  I bet 95% of the time when someone "means"  "ios how to get rid of the context menu" they type "iphone how to get rid of the context menu"

perhaps that's a factor here?

Comment: I am not familiar with iOS developers that type "iphone" when searching. Nor should anyone, like when you develop on Android, you don't search for "Nexus how to perform intent".

Comment: About searching tags, again, this is the incorrect search term.

Comment: @LeoNatan: No, I agree with Joe. Some devs do type iPhone or iPad, and much more often than you think. There's a much stronger identification with the device name on Apple platforms. Even I say that I develop iPhone and iPad apps — not iOS apps. iOS is pretty much an implementation detail on the Apple ecosystem. In fact, it's a brand that doesn't even belong to Apple, they use it under license.

Comment: Just like people using `xcode` to ask iOS-related questions - bad bad bad! `;-)`

Comment: Plus, there's the Google bias. Just compare: https://www.google.fr/search?rls=en&q=ios+development and https://www.google.fr/search?rls=en&q=iphone+development iPhone brings more than 7x more results than iOS.

Comment: Very true, Leo.

Comment: @KPM That's very imprecise. How many of these are helpful, technical resources, rather than just clueless sensationalist media articles? I'd argue the "iOS" results are better. We shouldn't encourage people to use wrong tags just because they are popular.

Comment: I agree that iOS results are better. It's not an argument about 'what's the best way to find results?' It's an argument about 'how do people name the things?' In the end, the question we need to answer is 'do we want people who use an improper term to find us or not?'

Comment: I think it is possible to disable tags and alert the user to use another. I think I've seen it. Someone more experienced may be able to answer.

Comment: @KPM you and Joe are right about search. However, this is really a self-reinforcing chicken-and-egg problem.  I know for my own Google searches that I usually try "iOS" first, and then try "iPhone" when "iOS" has no results.  I only do that because I know everyone else is doing it - if everyone else wouldn't do it, then it wouldn't be a problem, but someone has to start doing it right.

Comment: 'this is really a self-reinforcing chicken-and-egg problem' very true

Comment: Leo dude I really do think people (even engineers) use "iPhone" to me "Apple" or "iOS" -- to be clear, what I mean is in the same way (in outback Australia) "toyota" means "four wheel drive", or "Hoover" means vacuum-cleaner in many places, or (confusingly!) "coke" means "soft drink" (any flavour/brand) in many parts of the USA.  I really fear it is used that way you know?

Comment: @Joe Doesn't mean it should be condoned. Users should be educated, not enabled to use incorrect terms.

Comment: @JoeBlow Seriously, just look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24233713/983912 He just dumped the tags and hopes for the best `>_<`

Comment: heh all true -- its' a difficult issue.  Regarding this philosophical puzzler "Users should be educated, not enabled to use incorrect terms" ... my view of that market question is *How do I take their money?*  :)

Answer (score 0):

Although a tag-synonym would potentially work, there are actual uses for these hardware-specific tags.

That being said, the only real problem I have with [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone) and [ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipad) are that they are often used *instead* of the almighty [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios). This usually curses these questions with less attention than they would have potentially received with [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios). The same problem seems to occur with version-specific tags such as [ios8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios8) and [ios7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios7).

In both of the tags in question, there is a clause in the tag wiki excerpt that suggests the use of [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios), but I doubt anyone reads that far into the tag wiki when tagging a question (although they should).

So my answer is: *Leave it alone*. The only change I could reasonably see is tag wiki excerpts being calarified.

Comment: The problem is nobody reads tag wikis. If they did, `xcode` would not be used all the time.

Comment: @LeoNatan if we removed every tag that was misused there were not be many tags left

Comment: @connor There would not be _any_ tags left.

Comment: @connor That's terrible reasoning for not removing bad tags. Some tags are necessary and are abused (`xcode`). Others are unnecessary and are abused too. No reason to keep the latter.

Comment: The tag wikis do tell how the the tag should be used. Perhaps what we need is a system that prompts users to confirm they are using the tag in the correct way when they try to add a commonly misused tag.

Comment: @connor I'd imagine that that was part of the idea behind the "suggested tags" feature.

Comment: Couldn't that be part of the problem as well? If a user tags a question as ios and uses iphone in the question would it automatically suggest iphone?

Answer (score -8):

Wouldn't [cocoa-touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoa-touch) be a better tag for a majority of questions tagged [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) and [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone)?

In [cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoa)-land, most experienced posters don't tag every question [osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx). I tend to reserve it for questions about operating-system services and other things which are larger than an app (or "mac ruby"- or "mac python"-type questions). Most of the high-quality questions seem to follow that approach.

Congruently [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) might be useful for questions about Foundation, system services, the simulator, provisioning, and the like.

In other words, synonymizing doesn't seem like the best way to go…

Comment: [cocoa-touch] is only subset of [ios]

Comment: How does that relate to this answer?

Comment: [cocoa-touch] is not better tag for many questions tagged [ios] and [iphone]

Comment: So, keep all of them. My suggestion is to use [ios] selectively, not as an "almighty" umbrella.

Comment: @noa iOS **is** an umbrella of all Apple mobile development and operating systems.

Comment: You have a fair point here, especially the comparison to Cocoa/OS X, and indeed I (mostly try to) use those tags in the way you describe. I'm not sure it's feasible with [ios], though, given the inertia.