# Why can't I suggest a synonym between [ios] and [iphone]?

Tags: support, tag-synonym-process

[I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074289/objective-c-uncaught-exception-nsunknownkeyexception) [just](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433427/nsunknownkeyexception-setvalue-forundefinedkey-in-classfile) [spent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23673216/nsunknownkeyexception-reason-viewcontroller-0x8a45930-setvalueforundefi) [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987431/mkmapview-nsunknownkeyexception) [time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210036/uipickerview-nsunknownkeyexception) [marking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701373/nsunknownkeyexception-with-any-collectionview-object) [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120786/do-not-understand-error-message-about-nsunknownkeyexception) [bunch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9961599/nsunknownkeyexception-error-when-running-my-app) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058712/error-when-adding-buttons-on-uiviewcontroller-nsunknownkeyexception) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26630963/nsunknownkeyexception-while-alloc-and-init-of-uipopovercontroller) [as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138415/nsunknownkeyexception-storyboard-or-code) [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044064/nsunknownkeyexception-xcode-navigation-controller) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130074/nsunknownkeyexception-that-i-cant-find-a-fix-for) [each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242517/nsunknownkeyexception-exception-raised-applicaton-crashes) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249149/terminating-app-due-to-uncaught-exception-nsunknownkeyexception). Looking at the tags while doing so, I saw a bunch of [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone) and a bunch of [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios), and there didn't seem to be much distinction in their use.

I wanted to suggest they be synonyms (and found [some existing discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260593/making-iphone-ipod-touch-and-ipad-tags-synonyms-of-the-inclusive-ios) — we don't need to get into that right now), but I was thwarted by [iphone-os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone-os):

[image]

And in the opposite direction, [iphone-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone-sdk) gets in the way:

[image]

Is it impossible to vote for this synonym, or am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: This might also have something to do with the fact that they once were synonyms: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85188/break-the-ios-iphone-synonym but the community voted to remove that. Maybe that history is blocking them from becoming synonyms again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both tags [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone) and [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) already have other synonyms pointing towards them. Any tag which already has a synonym for it cannot be proposed as a synonym of another tag, because you end up with routes like this:

```
[master-tag] <- [intermediate-tag] <- [synonym]
```

In order to bypass restrictions like this, you have to get a moderator involved to either a) remove the existing synonyms of the tag you are trying to propose as a synonym or b) merge the tags, which will transfer all the existing synonyms to the new master tag.